# Tubular neighborhoods of embedding of manifolds and vector bundles

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes

in this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16240/why-is-it-useful-to-classify-the-vector-bundles-of-a-space) about characteristic classes it is answered this:

> If your space is a manifold, knowing the vector bundles over that
>   space amounts to knowing all of its tubular neighbourhoods when you
>   embed the space in another manifold. This frequently allows you to
>   find many relationships between the two manifolds.
>
> One classical application would be the proof that all smooth
>   embeddings $S^n \to S^{n+2}$ (co-dimension two embedding of a sphere in a
>   sphere) has a Seifert surface -- meaning there is an embedded,
>   orientable $n+1$-manifold $M \to S^{n+2}$ whose boundary is the
>   $n$-sphere. One of the main steps is showing that the $n$-sphere in
>   $S^{n+2}$ has a trivial tubular neighborhood.

I ask for some references where I can look at this more closely. To be concrete, I want further reference for:

- knowing the vector bundles over that space amounts to knowing all of its tubular neighborhoods when you embed the space in another manifold

> I think that tubular neighborhoods are always vector bundles (at least they are with the definition of Bott Tu). **But I don't know if every vector bundle can be seen as a tubular neighborhood of some submanifold?**

- Relationships between the two manifolds given by the tubular neighborhoods and the relation to the tubular neighborhoods.
- One classical application would be the proof that all smooth  embeddings $S^n \to S^{n+2}$ has a Seifert surface -- meaning there is an embedded, orientable $n+1$-manifold $M \to S^{n+2}$ whose boundary is the  $n$-sphere.
- One of the main steps is showing that the $n$-sphere in  $S^{n+2}$ has a trivial tubular neighborhood.

Any help would be appreciated.

By the way, I have looked at:

- Lee, Introduction to Smooth Manifolds, 2nd. ed.
- Bott and Tu, Differential forms in Algebraic Topology
- Tu, Introduction to Manifolds, 2nd ed.

I am looking at:

- Hirsch, Differential Topology

but I haven't found what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tautologically every vector bundle can be realized as a tubular neighborhood (in some manifold). Namely if $V \to M$ is a vector bundle, the inclusion $M\to V$ coming from the 0-section gives the normal bundle of $M$ as (something isomorphic to) $V$.

If the ambient manifold is fixed (for instance if you want to know what vector bundles are tubular neighborhoods are for $M \to \Bbb R^n$) the problem becomes a lot more subtle. As the tangent bundle of $\Bbb R^n$ is trivial, we have $T\Bbb R^n$ restricted to $M$ is $TM \oplus \nu$, so for $\nu$ arise as a normal bundle to an embedding (or an immersion even) $\nu$ must become trivial after summing with $TM$. This is not the only assumption, but it can get you a long way.

I'll give you a way to see every embedding $S^n \to \Bbb R^{n+2}$ is "framed" (the normal bundle is trivial) for $n\ne 2$. In fact, I'll show that every 2-dim bundle over $S^n$ is trivial. Further reading can be found in Milnor-Stasheff and probably and in any regular algebraic topology book to fill in the details.

One very nice thing about isomorphism classes of n-dimensional real vector bundles over $M$ is that they are in bijection to the homotopy class of a map $M \to BO(k)$. Here $BO(n)$ is called the classifing space of the orthogonal group, and can be decomposed into a direct limit $Gr(k,n)$ (the space of k-planes in $\Bbb R^n$).

The fact that our map comes from an embedding $S^n \to \Bbb R^{n+2}$ tells us that our classifying map factors through the inclusion $Gr(n,n+2) \to BO(2)$. So we get a map $f:S^n \to Gr(n,n+2)$, and we'll show that any such map is nullhomotopic.

Now $O(n)$ fibers over $Gr(k,n)$ with fiber $O(k)\times O(n-k)$. The long exact sequence for a fibration gives $\pi_n(O(n)\times O(2)) \to \pi_n(O(n+2)) \to \pi_n(Gr(n,n+2)) \to \pi_{n-1}(O(n) \times O(2))\to\pi_{n-1}(O(n+2))$, and another long exact sequence argument (prop 2.2 here https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/orthogonal+group) implies that the first and last arrows are surjective, so $\pi_n(Gr(n,n+2)$ is $0$.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on: "Namely if $V \to M$ is a vector bundle, the inclusion $M \to V$ coming from the 0-section gives the normal bundle of $M$ as (something isomorphic to) $V$ ." please? 



I have been trying to write that down but I am afraid I am missing something. What I have tried: Suppose $\sigma \colon M \to V$ is the zero section, $\sigma(p)=(p,0) \; \forall p \in M$. Then, is this the right exact sequence to obtain $V$ as the normal bundle?
$$0 \to T_{\sigma(M)} \to T_{V|\sigma(M)}\to N \to 0$$

Comment: Thanks in advance, I just want to formalize it a bit so I am sure I really understand it. And I feel there is still something that I don't see.